# IOSDriver can't resolve constructor, wants to cast DesiredCapabilities to Capabilities

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

```
package AppiumTest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

public class TestIOSSafariBrowser{
    @Test
    public void startBrowser() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone 8");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.4.1");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");

        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        System.out.println("Page title is " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to using Selenium and Appium.

I'm trying to open Safari to access Google through Xcode and Appium. When I instantiate IOSDriver as driver down below, IOSDriver does not allow me to pass in a DesiredCapabilities object (capabilities), instead expecting me to pass a Capabilities object. How would I try to open Safari and access the Google homepage if I use the Capabilities object instead of DesiredCapabilities, or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Don't you have to have a Before tag where you establish your driver that then gets passed into a Test tag and then gets closed by a After tag?

Comment: Hi LoflinA, are you referring to the before after tag as in CSS? How would that work into here?

Comment: No, I am referring to the testng attributes http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html